# Grails Asset Pipeline - minifyJs set to true not working

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin

I used grails asset pipeline plugin to minify my application (I don't have any problem when running grails run-app) the problem arises when I'm going to generate a war file to deploy into tomcat server.

Currently using **':asset-pipeline:1.9.9'**

currently My **Config.groovy** has this setup

```
grails.assets.minifyJs = true
grails.assets.minifyCss = true
grails.assets.bundle = true
```

The Particular problem here is when I'm going to set **minifyJs = true**

when I'm going to set **minifyJs = false** there's no error but my war file are not going to work when deployed to tomcat server.

```
| Error 2016-03-13 01:50:16,590 [main] ERROR pipeline.AssetCompiler  - Uglify JS Exception 
Message: [object Object] (/application/target/work/resources/uglifyjs/lib/parse-js.js#273)
Line | Method ->>  273 | _c_js_error_13 in org.mozilla.javascript.gen._application_target_work_resources_uglifyjs_lib_parse_js_js_2
```

I don't know whats going on or I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately above the error message lines you quoted should be lines like this:

```
| Processing File 851 of 888 - jquery/src/intro.js
| Uglifying File 851 of 888 - jquery/src/intro
```

Whatever javascript file that is mentioned there probably has either some syntax error, or possibly weird non-ascii characters that were introduced because of file encoding issues or something.

Comment: Yeah maybe, I'm not sure, there's no problem with the libraries importation the problem is on the angular file that I created, either  in the services I made or in the controller or something.

Comment: I'll check about it, maybe that the cause.

Comment: hi @redwolfgang20 did you find the solution?  I am also dealing with the same problem and the war build is taking a lot of time too :/

Comment: Hello @ani0904071, I already fix the problem a long time ago. As I remember the problem was all about my javascript file anuglarjs.

Comment: @ani0904071 may I know what version of grails you are using right now?

Comment: hi @redwolfgang20, the problem is that a few branches were being developed in parallel and were merged in a single release. so, it is really difficult to find a problem which piece of code did it, is there any way to find the problem through logs or some other way? 
I am using Grails legacy 2.3.8 version so quite old!

Comment: @ani0904071 were you able to produce a war file before you encounter the issue with the same project? If yes, then you have to check out each feature branch and try which branch is working and which branch is not working. That's how I trace and solve the issue.

Comment: hi @redwolfgang20, there is an option to make minifyJs to false like this: grails.assets.minifyJs = false, if I do that the the error is not happening during build, and the build is fast also, so should it be a problem If I deploy it in server?

Comment: @ani0904071 I think that's ok but there's a consequence. This is the reason why we need to minify that one.

Minification is the process of minimizing code and markup in your web pages and script files. It’s one of the main methods used to reduce load times and bandwidth usage on websites. Minification dramatically improves site speed and accessibility, directly translating into a better user experience. It’s also beneficial to users accessing your website through a limited data plan and who would like to save on their bandwidth usage while surfing the web.

Comment: hi @redwolfgang20, I get what you explained. I studied it from this link: https://gsmplusinfotech.com/blog/how-to-minify-static-resources-using-asset-pipeline/;
for the time being, I have disabled it during war create, and looking into the older branches which might have caused it. thanks for your explanation :)